# IE9 Print preview of java Applet/image issue duo to (interpolation it seems)

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-9, rendering, preview

I am Currently extending a finance application including a Html report solution, which was initially developped for ie5. now im using ie9.

im Having a problem with the rendering of images and Java Applets in the Print preview.

as seen in the images:
[Applet draws perfectly fine in Browser](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1484680/good%20print%20preview.PNG)
[but looks really ugly in print preview](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1484680/damn%20print%20preview.PNG)

looks like some fubard interpolation to me

had someone of you had simmilar issues, or even a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

edit: i forgot to add the applet code, to make you knwo what im dealing with

```
<applet name="" code="netcharts4.apps.NFPiechartApp" codebase="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/NetCharts/classes" archive="netcharts4.jar" class="pieChart">
        <param name="NFParamScript" value='
            Background                 = (white,NONE,1,null,TILE,black); 
            PieSquare                  = ON; 
            SliceData                  = <%=ch.getValuesforChart() %>; 
            Pie3DDepth                 = 20; 
            SliceLabelStyle            = EXTERIOR; 
            SliceLabelLine             = (SOLID,1,black); 
            SliceLabelContent          = LABEL; 
            SliceLabelContentDelimiter = "\n"; 
            SliceLabel                 = (ON,black,"Sans Serif",10,0); 
            SliceLabelBox              = (white,NONE,2); 
            SliceBorder                = (SOLID,1,black);
            SliceLabels                = <%=ch.getValuesforChartLegend() %>; 
            ColorTable                 = <%=ch.getColorTableForChart(ch.getDetails().size()) %>;
            AntiAlias                  = ON;'/> 
    </applet>
```

Comment: As seen in images I think the print preview zoom is more than 100%.

Comment: Yes it is, but thats not the problem, has seen in this [image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1484680/browser%20and%20print%20preview%20in%20same%20window.png) the print preview output looks also bad on 100% zoom. but when i zoom in(ctrl +) on the browser and then print, the image output is better, strangely

Comment: Apparently a java update to 1.7_025 resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found out that ie9 simply doesnt get get along well with java6, java7 displayed the applet better but had too long loading times. ie10 and 11 worked when java is proberly installed and usable (this requires chaning ie settings thou).
i ended up replacing the applet with a java scripled which generated a equally looking svg element